# finish Thread actions before activity continues

Tags: android

this is a piece of code from my project, i need this thread to be over untill the end and only then go to the last Log.i() and finish the function.

```
public void delay3Seconds(final String txt1, final String txt2, final String s, final Intent i)
    {
        //keepMoving= false;
        counter= 3;
        secondsBool= true;

        if(!errorMonitor)
        {  
            Log.i("Main.delay3Seconds()", s+" in 3 seconds");
            new Thread()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    while(secondsBool)
                    {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1500);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                        if(!errorMonitor)
                        {
                            handler.post(new Runnable()
                            {
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    final DialogFragment loadDF= new RecDialog(MainActivity.this, txt1, txt2, s+(counter--)+" שניות", null, false, true, ll.getWidth(), ll.getHeight());
                                    loadDF.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "RecDialog");
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    dialog= loadDF;
                                    if(counter == 0)
                                        secondsBool= false;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                            secondsBool= false;
                    }
                    if(!errorMonitor)
                    {
                        handler.post(new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) 
                                {
                                    Log.i("Main.delay3Seconds()", "resolveActivity != null");
                                    setResolveNotFail(true);
                                    Log.i("Main.delay3Seconds()", "resolveNotFail = "+resolveNotFail);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Log.i("Main.delay3Seconds()", "resolveActivity == null");
                                    setResolveNotFail(false);
                                    Log.i("Main.delay3Seconds()", "resolveNotFail = "+resolveNotFail);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }

        Log.i("Main.delay3Seconds()", "(end) resolveNotFail = "+resolveNotFail);
    }
```

i can't figure out how to do that. i tried using synchronized(), but i probably use it wrong because the function finishes itself first and only then the thread works, simultaneously to the activity.

i would appreciate any tips on how to do that..

Comment: That's not possible, you are starting a new thread. The original thread continues to run and will exit the function. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

That's absolutely not how or why you use a Thread.  First off, if this is the UI thread you should never pause it for 3 seconds.  Second, the entire point of a Thread is to work in parallel.  You never want one thread to pause and wait for another.  If you need something on Thread A to occur only when Thread B is done, you send a message via a handler, semaphore or other method to Thread A when Thread B is done.

Looking at your code, it seems like you should throw it out and reimplement it with a timer.

Comment: yes i am actually trying to make a timer. in my app when a user chooses to play a song for example, so the dialog shows a message " the song will be played in 3,2,1 seconds" and  after that it will launch the player that is on device, but if the app does'nt find the music player intent the "ResolveNotFail" will become false and then the activity will launch youtube.

Comment: so what you are saying is that i should;nt use a thread for that, so how do i make timer without a thread then?  untill now i made timer through threads..

Comment: There's a couple of methods.  For a brief period (a second or two) you can simply do a postDelayed to a Handler.  For a long period where you need to be woken up, an Alarm via AlarmManager.  There's also Timer and TimerTask if you need repeated execution.  For your use, I'd just use a delayed post to a Handler.  The advantage there is you're still on the main thread which is nice since all you're doing is simple UI updates.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html

Just call the .join() method after you start your thread so the calling thread will wait until your new thread executes. 
Something like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(...);
t.start();
t.join();
```